# Can we install ADF SHIR and Logic Apps on-prem Data Gateway on the same machine?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard, azure-data-factory

We understand that a VM on-prem hosts the SHIR and this then is registered to the ADF.

Can we use same VM for installing the on-prem Data Gateway for Logic apps or both need to be on separate machines?

Answer (score 1):

You can install Power BI SHIR and On Premises data gateway on the same server but it is ideally not recommended.

because both gateways communicate via same ports.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory